# Facebook SDK (/me) does not contain email although permission is given

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am using the PHP Facebook SDK on my website where users can connect there Facebook accounts. I want to get the user's email address. Permission is given by the user. But if I output facebook->api('/me') then there is no e-mail address. For all other extra information like 'user_likes' it works all fine.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Here is my code. I am using Codeigniter

```
    $fb_config = array(
                'appId'  => 'xxx',
                'secret' => 'xxx'
            );
     $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);

 $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

 if ($user) {
    try {
       $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       $user = null;
    }
else {
    $params['scope'] = "email";
    $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    }

print_r($data['user_profile'];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with another account? I had a similar problem once, the e-mail wasn't displayed for a specific user, and it worked well for others.

I ended up using username@facebook.com as an e-mail for this specific case, but never found out why it didn't work for this specific user.